# What is the difference between inputMode and keyboardType in TextInput Component of React Native?

Tags: react-native

What is the real difference between inputMode and keyboardType props of TextInput field in React Native and when would you use each one of them? It's hard to find any real evidence on what should be preferred to use. I did look into React native documentation, but I am looking for a more in-depth answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So basically ive used both, not major differences when used for native android app.

But the difference comes in when you use web apps or use ios app.

Try using

```
 <TextInput  style={{backgroundColor:'red'}} inputMode="numeric" />
```

In your ios device via expo snack [Expo snack](https://snack.expo.dev/@gaurav1995/laughing-tortilla)

You can see that keyboard of ios is not numeric

[image]

But if you use keyboardType you can see it specifically ensures numeric keyboard appears

[image]

Hope this helps.

Feel free for doubts

Comment: if you did like it, please upvote and mark as accepted too. will help